# Clear inbox for read chat notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

Currently, the multicollider shows notifications for chat messages(usually rolled up), even if the message has already been seen. Now, chat already has a mechanism for marking messages as "read", so can't the multicollider collaborate with this?

[image]

Aside from the "that's a bit rough" message, in the above screenshot, I'd been online at the time and had read the messages directly from chat (Mobile chat for the Periodic Table one, main chat for the Tavern).

Also, why is there a delay in receiving a message and getting a multicollider ping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. A chat message that I have not yet "read" is prefixed with "mention":

[image]

Tapping on the pink oval, it disappears and I get a normal chat message:

[image]

It does not show up in my chat inbox on the full site, nor does it eventually end up in my main inbox.

Comment: Nice, wonder why no dev popped here to get some fame. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ChrisF is secretly a dev, he just doesn't want us to know because he'll be teased till kingdom come on how he finally achieved his goal of getting all the diamonds.

Comment: Yeah, not to mention that he'll be added to The Wheel!

Answer (score 4):

You only get notified in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ if the message isn't acknowledged in chat (i.e. you didn't send any new messages or clear the notification icon) for a period of [about fifteen minutes](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=441977#441977). The delay prevents you from getting notifications for things you've already seen in chat.

The issue in your case is [with the mobile chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=441980#441980), which doesn't ever seem to consider the notifications to be acknowledged. Marc's response suggested at the time that this wasn't the expected behaviour, so I'm inclined to consider that aspect a bug.

Otherwise, I don't really see the benefit in removing the inbox notifications if you clear the notifications in the chat interface far after the fact, since I'm normally inclined to check my inbox first anyway if I've been away for a while. After I've seen them there, I'd not expect them to disappear once I dismissed them in chat (when applicable), so there's not a lot of gain there.